# How to get website using cURL

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, libcurl

I am not able to fetch data using cURL in php AS I can do this using `curl` command in terminal like below -

```
curl http://www.universalapplianceparts.com/search.aspx?find=w10130694
```

This command provide expected result in terminal.

I want same result in php using curl

Below is my php code -

```
$url = "http://www.universalapplianceparts.com/search.aspx?find=W10130694";
$ch = curl_init();  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.universalapplianceparts.com/");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    $output = curl_exec ($ch); 
    curl_close ($ch); 
    var_dump($output);
```

Please let me know why I am not getting same result using php curl as I am getting in terminal.

Thanks

Comment: what do you want to by this?

Comment: I want ot fetch html data in my browser as I am getting in terminal . I think something is missing in php code

Comment: As far as I can see, you are using a POST, while you're actually want to GET. I think if you change POST to GET and delete the postfields and header line, it should work...

Comment: check updated answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this ::

```
    $url = "http://www.universalapplianceparts.com/search.aspx?find=W10130694";
$ch1= curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch1,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,1);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; Media Center PC 4.0)');
curl_setopt ($ch1, CURLOPT_REFERER,'http://www.google.com');  //just a fake referer
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch1,CURLOPT_POST,0);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 20);

$htmlContent= curl_exec($ch1);
echo $htmlContent;
```

Comment: try above code ..it will help you...its working for me

Comment: Perfect.. thats what I needed. Perfectly works.. But Can you please explain it. So I can understand it properly that what I am doing.. I dont want to just use this I also want to learn. and it will also helps to many fellows also

Comment: look you first need to learn what is curl and how it works. please refer http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php this will help you..

Comment: This code provides proper OP but while writing regexp for particular div it again returns complete html. can you check once. this is my regexp `preg_match_all('/.*<div.*class=\"product\-list\-options\".*>.*<a href=\"(.*)\">.*<\/a>.*<\/div>/s',$htmlContent,$matches);` I need only href value

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
 $url = "http://www.universalapplianceparts.com/search.aspx?find=W10130694";
                $options = Array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,  
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,  
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Content-Type: application/text"),
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 120,  
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.1a2pre) Gecko/2008073000 Shredder/3.0a2pre ThunderBrowse/3.2.1.8",
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,  
    );

    $ch = curl_init(); 

    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);  

    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: I am still getting error page while fetching data. can you check terminal command output it shows proper complete html code in terminal same output should be dispalyed in browser so I can copy content from that output

Comment: It returns nothing. complete blank page

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and getting error related to length so you need to add content length as well in your curl request. Try below code hope it will help you :

```
$url = "http://www.universalapplianceparts.com/search.aspx?find=W10130694";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/text"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, array("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.1a2pre) Gecko/2008073000 Shredder/3.0a2pre ThunderBrowse/3.2.1.8"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Length: 0'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: kindly add below as well curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, array("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.1a2pre) Gecko/2008073000 Shredder/3.0a2pre ThunderBrowse/3.2.1.8"));

Comment: its is showing object moved page.. not showing result

Comment: Have you added *USER AGENT*.

Comment: yes.. also I tried accepted answer but it returns complete html again in regexp. still my regexp should fetch only href content from div class in anchor tag, this is my regexp `preg_match_all('/.*<div.*class=\"product\-list\-options\".*>.*<a href=\"(.*)\">.*<\/a>.*<\/div>/s',$htmlContent,$matches);`